# Bootstrap select pass value with disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, select

I am using bootstrap Select, https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/

```
if ( $('#po_currency').val() == $('#business_currency').val() ) {
    $('.tax_rate').selectpicker();
} else {
    $('.tax_rate').selectpicker('val', 4);
    $('.tax_rate').prop('disabled', true);
    $('.tax_rate').selectpicker('refresh');
}
```

I am using the above code, to set value as per condition, but when I disabled select picker, it does not pass value to the server,

Is there any solution for data to pass when select is disabled?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of disabling the `select` element itself, you can [disable the bootstrap replacement](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/examples/#disabled) and prevent user interaction by using [`setStyle`](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/methods/#selectpickersetstyle).

```
if ( $('#po_currency').val() == $('#business_currency').val() ) {
    $('.tax_rate').selectpicker();
} else {
    $('.tax_rate').selectpicker('val', 4).selectpicker('setStyle', 'disabled')});
}
```